# CPU Timeout Error When Inserting 2000 Records through Apex

Tags: apex, error, dml, data, cpulimit

I created an apex class that is activated by a button for a 1 time use insert of about 2000 enrollment records.  The code works with small amounts of records but when with the full 2000 I get a timeout limit.  There are a few flows that are triggered "after create" which may be causing the issue but I was unsure if there were any glaring issues with the code that would cause this slow-down.

I assign the values to the fields for each item in both lists, insert them to create the Ids, and then relate them to each others Id and upsert the values to include the linked values.

Thanks!

```
global class EnrollmentMassInsert {
    
    public EnrollmentMassInsert(){}
    
    @InvocableMethod(label='Enrollment Mass Insert')
    global static void massInsert() {
        String reportingPeriod = '2021';
        List<Account> accountList = [
            SELECT Id, Name, SPA_Account__c 
            FROM Account
            WHERE RecordType.Name = 'SARA Account'
            AND Join_Date__c < 2022-01-01
            AND Institution_Status__c = 'Participant'
        ];
        
        system.debug(accountList);
        
        List<Enrollemnt__c> enrollmentList = new List<Enrollemnt__c>();
        List<Experiential_Enrollment__c> ooslpList = new List<Experiential_Enrollment__c>();
        for(Integer i=0; i<accountList.size(); i++){
            try{
                enrollmentList.add(new Enrollemnt__c(
                    Institution__c = accountList[i].Id,
                    SPA_Account__c = accountList[i].SPA_Account__c,
                    Reporting_Period__c = reportingPeriod,
                    Due_Date__c = date.newInstance(2022, 06, 15)
                ));
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.debug('An unexpected error has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
            }
            try{
                ooslpList.add(new Experiential_Enrollment__c(
                    Institution__c = accountList[i].Id,
                    SPA_Account__c = accountList[i].SPA_Account__c,
                    Reporting_Period__c = reportingPeriod,
                    Due_Date__c = date.newInstance(2022, 06, 15)
                ));
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.debug('An unexpected error has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        insert ooslpList;
        insert enrollmentList;
        
        for (Integer i=0; i<ooslpList.size(); i++){
            //assign linked ooslp to enrollments
            enrollmentList[i].Linked_OOSP__c = ooslpList[i].Id;
            //assign linked enrollment to ooslp
            ooslpList[i].Linked_Enrollment__c = enrollmentList[i].Id;
        }
        upsert ooslpList;
        upsert enrollmentList;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to optimize your code by minimizing the number of `size()` methods you have to call, as well as minimizing heap usage by not dynamically extending your lists. Also, upsert is less efficient than update when you know it's an update. Here's how I might refactor this:

```
public class EnrollmentMassInsert {
    @InvocableMethod(label='Enrollment Mass Insert')
    public static void massInsert() {
        String reportingPeriod = '2021';
        List<Account> accountList = [
            SELECT Id, Name, SPA_Account__c 
            FROM Account
            WHERE RecordType.Name = 'SARA Account'
            AND Join_Date__c < 2022-01-01
            AND Institution_Status__c = 'Participant'
        ];
        Date dueDate = Date.newInstance(2022, 06, 15);
        Integer accountListSize = accountList.size();
        List<Enrollemnt__c> enrollmentList = new List<Enrollemnt__c>[accountListSize];
        List<Experiential_Enrollment__c> ooslpList = new List<Experiential_Enrollment__c>[accountListSize];
        for(Integer i=0; i<accountListSize; i++){
            enrollmentList[i] = new Enrollemnt__c(
                Institution__c = accountList[i].Id,
                SPA_Account__c = accountList[i].SPA_Account__c,
                Reporting_Period__c = reportingPeriod,
                Due_Date__c = dueDate
            );
            ooslpList[i] = new Experiential_Enrollment__c(
                Institution__c = accountList[i].Id,
                SPA_Account__c = accountList[i].SPA_Account__c,
                Reporting_Period__c = reportingPeriod,
                Due_Date__c = dueDate
            );
        }
        insert ooslpList;
        insert enrollmentList;
        
        for (Integer i=0; i<accountListSize; i++){
            //assign linked ooslp to enrollments
            enrollmentList[i].Linked_OOSP__c = ooslpList[i].Id;
            //assign linked enrollment to ooslp
            ooslpList[i].Linked_Enrollment__c = enrollmentList[i].Id;
        }
        update ooslpList;
        update enrollmentList;
    }
}
```

That said, you need to enable profiling to find out where your main CPU time sinks are. Set up a [Debug Log Level](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=code_setting_debug_log_levels.htm&type=5&language=en_US) with all values set to the minimum, except for PROFILING, which should be set to FINEST. From there, test your code in a unit test, and check out the resulting log file. You'll get summary-level information on which methods are taking the longest. Focus on those first.

If you're using after-save flows, check if they can be made before-save flows. This can easily double the performance of saving records. Alternatively, consider using triggers; Apex is still generally better than using flows, but only marginally in most cases. However, if you really need the extra performance, it's something worth looking in to.

Finally, if that's just not enough, consider moving your logic to a future or Queueable system instead. You won't get immediate results back, but it will allow you to have six times the CPU limit, which should suffice.

Comment: Awesome feedback.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Building on sfdcfox's answer...

The try/catch statements that you have right now should be removed. They shouldn't be using any significant CPU time, but swallowing exceptions is bad practice (as is only writing something to the debug log when you run into an exception). If you can't articulate *what* error you think could happen, then you probably shouldn't put it in a try/catch.

Beyond that, you're using more DML statements than you need to here. Any DML you perform can only increase the CPU time consumed. Less DML, less processing.

You can remove one of the update DML statements by using a map to tie the Account Id to your `Enrollemnt__c` instance and another map to tie the Account Id to your `Experiential_Enrollment__c` instance.

- Insert one of the maps
- Iterate over the other to set your relationship field
- Insert the second map
- Iterate over the first map to set your relationship field
- Update the first map

```java
Map<Id, Enrollemnt__c> accountIdToEnrollment = new Map<Id, Enrollemnt__c>();
Map<Id, Experiential_Enrollment__c> accountIdToOoslp = new Map<Id, Experiential_Enrollment__c>();
for(Integer i = 0; i < accountListSize; i++){
    accountIdToEnrollment.put(accountList[i].Id, new Enrollemnt__c(
        Institution__c = accountList[i].Id,
        SPA_Account__c = accountList[i].SPA_Account__c,
        Reporting_Period__c = reportingPeriod,
        Due_Date__c = dueDate
    ));
    accountIdToOoslp.put(accountList[i].Id, new Experiential_Enrollment__c(
        Institution__c = accountList[i].Id,
        SPA_Account__c = accountList[i].SPA_Account__c,
        Reporting_Period__c = reportingPeriod,
        Due_Date__c = dueDate
    ));
}

// We can't insert a map directly, but we can insert the result of .values() (if the
//   map's value type is an SObject and not a collection of SObjects)
insert accountIdToOoslp.values();

for(Experiential_Enrollment__c experimentalEnrollment :accountIdToOoslp.values()){
    // The experimental enrollment records have their Id after the insert DML returns
    //   control
    accountIdToEnrollment.get(experimentalEnrollment.Institution__c).Linked_OOSP__c = experimentalEnrollment.Id;
}

insert enrollmentList;

for(Enrollment__c enrollment :accountIdToEnrollment.values()){
    accountIdToOoslp.get(enrollment.Institution__c).Linked_Enrollment__c = enrollment.Id;
}

update accountIdToOoslp.values();
```

Also, since you now aren't using `accountList` outside of the first loop, you can have your query directly feed your first loop (a.k.a. a SOQL for loop) going from

```
String reportingPeriod = '2021';
List<Account> accountList = [
        SELECT Id, Name, SPA_Account__c 
        FROM Account
        WHERE RecordType.Name = 'SARA Account'
        AND Join_Date__c < 2022-01-01
        AND Institution_Status__c = 'Participant'
    ];
    
system.debug(accountList);

List<Enrollemnt__c> enrollmentList = new List<Enrollemnt__c>();
List<Experiential_Enrollment__c> ooslpList = new List<Experiential_Enrollment__c>();
for(Integer i=0; i<accountList.size(); i++){
```

to

```
String reportingPeriod = '2021';

Map<Id, Enrollemnt__c> accountIdToEnrollment = new Map<Id, Enrollemnt__c>();
Map<Id, Experiential_Enrollment__c> accountIdToOoslp = new Map<Id, Experiential_Enrollment__c>();
for(Account acct : [SELECT Id, Name, SPA_Account__c FROM Account WHERE RecordType.Name = 'SARA Account' AND Join_Date__c < 2022-01-01 AND Institution_Status__c = 'Participant'){
    // All instances of "accountsList[i]"  would be replaced with "acct"
    //   inside this loop
```